# dividing using shifting in MIPS with remainder

Tags: mips, qtspim

I have written code in MIPS to calculate the sum of 8 numbers and then I used

`srl  $t4, $t3, 3     #divide by 8`

to get the average of the numbers, the sum was 12299 and the average was 1537.375, however, when I perform the right-shifting to compute the average the remainder, "375" gets dropped off.

what I am trying to do is print the average as "1537" then print a decimal, "." and then the remainder. That is how the assignment is set up, I am able to print the average plus the decimal, "1537." but I am not sure how to compute the remainder in MIPS and print it and would like to know how I can do that.

I have extensively looked online without any luck

Comment: What you're talking about is the fractional part. The term remainder has a different meaning. Anyway, if you want a floating-point result, use floating-point operations.

Comment: You could of course do something like `((12299 & 7) * 1000 + 4) >> 3)` if you're ok with hardcoding rounding to 3 decimal places.

Comment: As implied by Michael's comments, & with 7 gives the remainder of division by 8.  A formula is 2^3=8, so shift right by 3 to divide by 8, and with powers of 2, remainder can be computed with "and" operation, using mask of (1<<3)-1=8-1=7, or ..00111 in binary.